# How do you specify 'DEFAULT' as a SQL parameter value in ADO.NET?

Tags: sql, t-sql, ado.net, parameterized-query

I have a parameterized SQL query targetted for SQL2005 which is dynamically created in code, so I used the ADO.NET `SqlParameter` class to add sql parameters to `SqlCommand`.

In the aforementioned SQL I select from a Table Valued Function with has defaults. I want my dynamic sql to sometimes specify a value for these default parameters, and other times I want to specify that the SQL `DEFAULT` - as defined in the Table Valued Function - should be used.

To keep the code *clean* I didn't want to dynamically add the SQL `DEFAULT` keyword and parameterize it when a non-default is to be used, I just wanted to set `DEFAULT` as the value of my `SQLParameter`.

Can I? What is best practice in such an instance?

Comment: SQL "DEFAULT" keyword?  There're default constraints, which allow you to set a default value in the case that one isn't provided for the column...

Comment: @OMG Ponies: You can use `DEFAULT` in an `INSERT` (or `UPDATE`) statement just like you can use `NULL`: `INSERT INTO foo(col1, col2) VALUES(1234, DEFAULT)`.  This is standard SQL but little-known.

Comment: @Bill Karwin: Thx, definitely news to me.

Comment: It is even possible to pass `DEFAULT` to a TVF. However, SQL does not appear to like using `DEFAULT` in function that you passed to TVF (i.e. `Coalesce(@Foo, DEFAULT)`).

Comment: This might interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464535/preparing-a-mysql-insert-update-statement-with-default-values

Answer (score 15, accepted):

SQL query parameters take the place of literal values *only*.

You can't send an SQL keyword as the value of a parameter, just as you cannot send a table identifier, column identifier, list of values (e.g. for an `IN` predicate), or an expression.  The value of the parameter is *always* interpreted as a literal value, as if you had included a quoted string literal or a numeric literal in your query.

Sorry, but you have to include an SQL keyword as part of the SQL query *before* you prepare that query.

Comment: Yeah, its a bummer. I understand why but just makes things a little sticky for me :)

Comment: Also in stored procedures if you set `SqlParameter.Value` to `null`, it automatically sent `default` value to SQL Server. If you want to set database field to `null` use `DBNull.Value`.

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK, the only way to tell SQL Server to use a default value is via the `DEFAULT` keyword or to exclude it from parameter list. That means that the use of the `DEFAULT` keyword must be in your parameterized SQL Statement. So, something like:

```
Select ...
From dbo.udf_Foo( DEFAULT, @Param2, @Param3, DEFAULT, .... )
```

I suppose another approach would be to query the system catalogs for the actual value of the various `DEFAULT` values and determine whether to set the SqlParameter to the default value that way, but that requires a convoluted second query to get the default values.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the following function (for example):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.UFN_SAMPLE_FUNCTION 
(
    @Param1 nvarchar(10), 
    @Param2 int = NULL
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN 
   SELECT @Param1 AS Col1, @Param2 AS Col2;
GO
```

Then you can use it the following way (option 1):

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.UFN_SAMPLE_FUNCTION ('ABC', DEFAULT);
```

which is correct way and you get the following result:

```
Col1       Col2
---------- -----------
ABC        NULL
```

But if you try to use parametrized query (option 2):

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM dbo.UFN_SAMPLE_FUNCTION (@P1, @P2)',N'@P1 nvarchar(10),@P2 int',@P1=N'abc',@P2=default;
```

you will get an error:

```
Msg 8178, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
The parameterized query '(@P1 nvarchar(10),@P2 int)SELECT * FROM dbo.UFN_SAMPLE_FUNCTION' expects the parameter '@P2', which was not supplied.
```

If you have the following .net code:

```
public void RunTVF(string param1, int? param2)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = GetProdConection())
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.UFN_SAMPLE_FUNCTION (@P1, @P2)", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            var param = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@P1",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                Size = 10   ,
                Value = param1
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            param = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@P2",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                Value = param2
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

            cmd.Connection.Open();
            using (IDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then, in case param2 = null as Jack suggested above, the script produced by the code will be identical to the option 2 and will result to the same error. So you cannot use *NULL* in this case.You cannot set *DEFAULT* as the value of SQLParameter either.

What you can do is to create a stored procedure to wrap the call to your funcion and move your default value from the function to the SP. Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.USP_SAMPLE_PROCEDURE
( 
    @Param1 nvarchar(10), 
    @Param2 int = NULL, --DEFAULT value now is here (remove it from the function)
    @Statement nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    EXEC sp_executesql @Statement,N'@P1 nvarchar(10),@P2 int',@P1=@Param1,@P2=@Param2;
END
```

The .NET code will look the following way:

```
public void RunWrapper(string param1, int? param2)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = GetProdConection())
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("USP_SAMPLE_PROCEDURE", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            var param = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@Param1",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                Size = 10,
                Value = param1
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            param = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@Param2",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                Value = param2
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            param = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@Statement",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                Size = -1, //-1 used in case you need to specify nvarchar(MAX)
                Value = "SELECT * FROM dbo.UFN_SAMPLE_FUNCTION (@P1, @P2)"
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

            cmd.Connection.Open();
            using (IDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case *null* as a value for the *param2* will be translated to the correct *DEFAULT* and the following script will be produced:

```
exec USP_SAMPLE_PROCEDURE @Param1=N'ABC',@Param2=default,@Statement=N'SELECT * FROM dbo.UFN_SAMPLE_FUNCTION (@P1, @P2)'
```

which will give you the following result:

```
Col1       Col2
---------- -----------
ABC        NULL
```

I am not sure that this is the best practice. This is just the work-around.

Comment: The problem with this is it assumes that [null] implies [default], which may not always be the case.  This problem is a real shortcoming in Microsoft's implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Though you can't set an SQL keyword as the value of a parameter, you could in this case go and get the DEFAULT VALUE.

```
 SELECT COLUMN_DEFAULT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
      WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name'"
```

Comment: A default value can be a SQL Expression, including calling a function. Thus, this isn't generally useful on the .NET side.

Comment: @MgSam Not totally...this gets the DEFAULT value form the system catalogue...which can then be passed as a parameter...not elegant but sticking with the OP's original question. Or are we talking about different things?

Answer (score -1):

if you pass a dot net null value as the parameter value it will use sql DEFAULT
if you pass a dot net DBNull.Value it will use sql NULL

Comment: -1 This is not true. When calling a stored procedure in the context of `SqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text`, you can  indicate that a parameter that has a default value should actually use that default by either not defining the parameter, not setting it, or setting it to `null` as in `SqlParameter.Value = null;`. But this is not the same as using the T-SQL `DEFAULT` (which is what this question is about). It is the same as calling the proc without the param. And this question is specific to TVFs, not stored procedures, and TVFs do not allow for not specifying all of the input params.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to pass DEFAULT **via a Parameter** to a TVF call?  My research indicates no, it is not possible, you must detect no value being specified and manually replace the @ParameterName in the SqlText itself with DEFAULT.  That's my current belief anyways.

Comment: @srutzky That was to you