# Why when I insert a DateTime null I have "0001-01-01" in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, null, default

I try to insert the value null (DateTime) in my database for a field typed 'date' but I always get a *'0001-01-01'*. I don't understand, this field "allow nulls" and I don't know why I have this default value.

I'm using C# asp .net with MVC (Entity Framework), this is my code :

```
Budget_Synthesis newBS = new Budget_Synthesis
{
    Budget_Code = newBudgetCode,
    Last_Modified_Date = null
};
db.Budget_Synthesis.AddObject(newBS);
```

Last_Modified_Date is typed System.DateTime? so I don't know why they change this 'null'.

If I try to display the value on my application I get `01/01/0001 00:00:00`

And `0001-01-01` with SSMS

Someone can explain me why I can't get a real 'NULL' ?

Best regards

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: you are inserting a c# value of null datetime into a sqldatetime field?

Comment: How are you trying to insert? This matters. A lot.

Comment: How are you inserting. Through an application or sql mgmt studio?

Comment: Dose your DateTime is Nullable?

Comment: sql server cannot even **store** 0001-01-01; the minimum value in sql server is January 1, 1753. Where are you seeing this 0001-01-01, **exactly**?

Comment: @MarcGravell - Maybe he meant `datetime2`?

Comment: You could use the sql profiler to see what exactly you are trying to parse into the table

Comment: @Corak yeah, there's a lot of "maybe" in this question. What we need is more detail (hint Alex! more detail please!)

Comment: Re the latest edit: you show some code that adds an object to what looks to be an ORM of some kind. Right; we're getting somewhere... what ORM is this? What is that `AddObject` ? How is this all configured? What you *haven't* told us is anything about how all this gets to the database...

Comment: I edit with my C# code. I see '0001-01-01' with SQL Manager and "01/01/0001 00:00:00" if I try to display the data in my app.

Comment: You should create the Last_Modified_Date  to allow nullable value

Comment: @MarcGravell I use EntityFramework so I don't really have the detail of the request but I didn't have this kind of problem before, I always get 'null' for every kind of data except 'date' type.
Last_Modified_Date is suppose to accept nullable value because it's linked with my DB where I checked "allow nulls" with SQL Manager.

Comment: "If I try to display the value on my application I get..."
What do you get when you query in SSMS?

Comment: @JohnDewey With `SELECT Last_Modified_Date FROM Budget_Synthesis` I get `0001-01-01`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is the value corresponding to the null

Comment: @Andomar which is all well and good, but that isn't what this answer says

Comment: @MarcGravell: Comment was meant as additional information.  If you run `var d = new DateTime(); Console.WriteLine(d);`, it prints `0001-01-01`, which makes me disagree with the downvotes.

Comment: @Andomar yes, I'm well aware of the zero behaviour of datetime; but without a **lot** more context from the OP, this is just a random factoid. Indeed, the code now edited into the question shows use of `null`, which indicates that the type is most likely `DateTime?`. The default of `DateTime?` is *not* 0001-01-01

Comment: @MarcGravell: Yeah, I presume nHibernate, Linq2Sql or EF converts the `null` to a `DateTime` somewhere, and that ends up as `0001-01-01`.  Perhaps the column is marked as non-nullable in EF.  In a way `null` corresponds to `0001-01-01`, which is what this answer says.  Might not be a stellar answer, but it's from a new user, and I don't feel this deserves downvotes at all.

Answer (score 7):

If `Last_Modified_Date` is of type `DateTime`, you can't have "real null" because [DateTime structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.DATETIME%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) - as others already said- is not nullable. So your sample code will not even compile.

If `Last_Modified_Date` is of type `DateTime?` (`Nullable<DateTime>`) your code is correct, but -as @Nikola Dimitroff said in his answer- you can't have "real null" in your database because the default value for `DateTime?` is 01/01/0001 00:00:00.

The "real null" you are looking for is `DBNull.Value`, but you can use it only for [System.DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.DBNULL%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) type; if you assign `Last_Modified_Date = DBNull.Value` , whatever the type of `Last_Modified_Date` is, your code will not compile.

Answer (score 3):

When saying you are trying to put a null `DateTime`, are you using a `Nullable<DateTime>` (a.k.a `DateTime?`) or simply `DateTime`? The latter is a value type and its default value is precisely `01/01/0001 00:00:00`

Comment: Based on the code sample that assigns `null` to what is *presumably* a date, we know that it cannot be `DateTime`; thus `DateTime?` is the most likely

Comment: @NikolaDimitroff It's a `System.DateTime?` generated by EntityFramework when I linked my Models with the DB, that's why I can give him a 'null' but I don't knwo why he changes it in this default value.

Answer (score 0):

As for ADO.NET (and at least as of .NET 4.7), passing `null` (for example using `ExecuteNonQuery`) is translated to SQL `DEFAULT` keyword.

This can be verified using SQL Server Profiler.

For example, the following code:

```
var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
sqlCommand.CommandText = "EXEC CreateLog @UserName, @CreatedOn";
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", "George");
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedOn", (DateTime?)null);
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

is translated to:

```
exec sp_executesql N'EXEC CreateLog @UserName, @CreatedOn',
    N'@UserName nvarchar(6), @CreatedOn nvarchar(4000)',
    @UserName=N'George',@CreatedOn=default
```

This should normally just result in the following error:

> The parameterized query [...] expects the parameter '@CreatedOn', which was not supplied.

More details can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25832895/3002584).

Answer (score 0):

When u write the migration , be aware that u type `defaultValue:null` and make `DateTime?` in the model class also

```
public DateTime? FieldEx { get; set; }
```

```
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<DateTime>(
               name: "FieldEx",
               table: "tableEx",
               type: "datetime2",
               nullable: true,
               defaultValue:null);
```

Answer (score -3):

### In python programming language. The return type of the code:

```
print(type(df['col_name'].get(key='0001-01-01 BC')))
<class 'NoneType'>
```

It is not null, being more specific it is of ***NoneType***.