# Unable to insert default DateTime of C# to SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, default, sqlexception

I'm working on a C# console application project. Trying to insert a `DateTime` value into SQL Server 2008 and this is working good. In case if my code fails I want to insert the **default** `DateTime` to the table in database.

When I tried to insert I got an error.

> SqlTypeException was unhandled:
>   SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Below I have pasted the specific code.

```
try
{
  ...
  return DateTime.Now;
}

catch (WebException ex)
{
  ...
  return default(DateTime);
}
```

Code I used to insert details in the LOGS table:

```
connection.Open();
for (int i = 0; i < LogList.Count; i++)
    {
        string aprocessLogQuery = "INSERT INTO PROCESS_LOGS VALUES (@fileId, @startTime, @endTime, @transferredTime)";
        command = new SqlCommand(aprocessLogQuery, connection);
        command.Parameters.Add("fileId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = LogList[i].fileId;
        command.Parameters.Add("startTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = LogList[i].fileGeneration_StartDateTime;
        command.Parameters.Add("endTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = LogList[i].fileGeneration_EndDateTime;
        command.Parameters.Add("transferredTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = LogList[i].fileTransferred_DateTime;
        dataReader.Close();
        dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
    }
connection.Close();
```

The default value of `DateTime` is `01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM`, therefore it is not working.  Can anyone please suggest alternate working solution?

Thanks

Comment: you should use the [datetime2 datatype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334143/sql-server-datetime2-vs-datetime)

Comment: It would be a good idead to use SqlParameter instead of strings. Whenever I see a string query, I see the risk of SQL injection...

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692647/why-when-i-insert-a-datetime-null-i-have-0001-01-01-in-sql-server/16693888#16693888): it says that inserting `null` datetime give the default value in database.

Comment: @V4Vendetta Thanks for introducing datetime2.  But sorry I don't have access to change the dataType in SQL Server.

Comment: `DATETIME` in SQL Server doesn't support dates before the year 1753 - so if you cannot change your SQL Server datatype to `DATETIME2` (which would support `01/01/0001`), then you need to change your .NET code to return `01/01/1900` or something like that as a default

Comment: @user1671639 i guess your field is non nullable, so if you can't change the datatype you will have to pass in the min sql datetime value `1\1\1753`

Comment: @KamilT - They are using parameters.

Answer (score 4):

In the database, an unknown date is represented with `NULL` value.  You can insert that like:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startTime", DBNull.Value);
```

(As far as I know, it's required to prefix your parameters with `@`.)

Comment: The `@` prefix is optional there.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative solution is you can work around by build extension method look like as below:

```
public static class DateTimeExtension
{
    public static DateTime DefaultSqlDateTime(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
       return new DateTime(1753, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

and instead of `return default(DateTime)` you can use variable dateTime `return dateTime.DefaultSqlDateTime;`

**EDIT:**
How to use extension method:

E.g: `return default(DateTime).GetDefaultSqlDateTime();`

or

```
DateTime dateTime = ...
return dateTime.GetDefaultSqlDateTime();
```

Comment: Thanks.  But `return DateTime.DefaultSqlDateTime` is not working. Can you please explain?

Comment: @user1671639 Ah, I see you wonder about how to use DefaultSqlDateTime extension method. Please see edit part below.

Comment: Still I can't make through it.  Following the error `Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class`

Comment: Yes. You can look at the link : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19963/AddBusinessDay-DateTime-Extension-Method to get more understand about extension method on DateTime type. I have applied many extensions method on DateTime when deal with SQL Server that will help your code readable and more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this function in my Utilities instead of regular TryParse

```
public static bool TryParseSqlDateTime(string someval, DateTimeFormatInfo dateTimeFormats, out DateTime tryDate)
    {
        bool valid = false;
        tryDate = (DateTime)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue;
        System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime sdt;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(someval, dateTimeFormats, DateTimeStyles.None, out tryDate))
        {
            try
            {
                sdt = new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime(tryDate);
                valid = true;
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException ex)
            {


            }
        }

        ret
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, this will return minimum date value that SQL will accept. This method return DateTime in .Net.

```
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value
```