# Correct way to use default DateTime in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a SQL Server database. One of my tables has a SQL `DATETIME` column. This column should not have to be entered when the record is created, but later should be modified.

I understand that `DateTime` is not nullable. The default for `datetime2` is 1/1/0001, while the minimum value for SQL Server is 1/1/1753.

[Why when I insert a DateTime null I have "0001-01-01" in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692647/why-when-i-insert-a-datetime-null-i-have-0001-01-01-in-sql-server)

So, my question is what is the correct way to do this? How do I set `po.PODate` to the minimum for SQL Server (1/1/1753).

```
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

PurchaseOrder po = new PurchaseOrder();
po.PODate = new DateTime(1753, 1, 1);    // Best way?
// po.PODate = DateTime.MinValue;  Doesn't work because DateTime.MinValue is 1/1/0001
// po.PODate = null;               Doesn't work because DateTime is non-nullable value type
// po.PODate = DBNull.value;       Doesn't work because it is for type System.DBNull not DateTime

db.PurchaseOrders.Add(po);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Why you don't use `DateTime.Now` when the record is created?

Comment: I don't want the default value for PODate to be the current time, I want it to be some "ridiculous" DateTime that should never happen. Later on, the time will be changed to a realistic DateTime.

Comment: Then just modify you property to accept null. `DateTime PODate { get; set; }` to `DateTime? PODate { get; set; }`. Providing false (or ridiculous) data is not a best practice. If you don't need the data set it as `NULL` and update its value later on.

Comment: `DATETIME` in SQL Server ***is*** nullable - no problem at all. And `DATETIME2(n)` has a date range of years 0001 through 9999 - the 1/1/1753 **only** applies to `DATETIME` (which is one of the reasons one should start phasing that type out and use `DATETIME2(n)` instead)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expect the date to be not nullable, then yes, what you have is the best way.  EF will always pass in a value to that field regardless, so if  you don't, it will try to pass in 1/1/0001 and error.

Rather than have to define it each time, you could create a static class with:

```
public static DateTime MinDate()
{
   return new DateTime(1753, 1, 1);
}
```

If you wanted to standardize it.

The other option is make the column nullable, and anytime you query the date out, have SQL return 1/1/1753 when null.

Comment: Hmm, I only use it in one location so I don't think it's worth creating the static class. But, yes that is what I was looking for if I were to be using it in a lot of places. For the nullable thing, I did try overriding the method OnModelCreating in IdentityModel.ApplicationDbContext (but it didn't do anything) like so: ` modelBuilder.Entity<PurchaseOrder>().Property(m => m.PODate).IsOptional();
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);`

Comment: If you were trying the nullable thing; then you can change the type to "DateTime?".  If it's DateTime I don't know that IsOptional() will help, but potentially, you could use that to set it to 1/1/1753 maybe?