# SQLite default value if null

Tags: sqlite, insert, null, default-value

Let's say I have a table called "table"

So

```
Create Table "Table" (a int not null, b int default value 1)
```

If I do a "`INSERT INTO "Table" (a) values (1)`".  I will get back 1 for column a and 1 for column b as the default value for column b is 1.

BUT if I do "`INSERT INTO "Table" (a, b) values (1, null)`".  I will bet back 1 for column a and an empty value for column b.  Is there a way to set a column's default value if a null was given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you are doing:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (a, b) values (1, null)
```

You are **explicitely** asking for a `null` value on `b` column.

In a RDBMS you could technically use a trigger to override that behavior. But in SQLite you can't.

Answer (score 2):

1. If the column with the default value can have the NOT NULL constraint, then you can:

   - create the table using this syntax:

     `CREATE TABLE "Table" (a INT NOT NULL, b INT NOT NULL ON CONFLICT REPLACE DEFAULT 1);`

     and insert as usual
   - create the table as in your question

     and insert using this syntax:

     `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO "Table" (a, b) VALUES(1, null);`

https://database.guide/convert-null-values-to-the-columns-default-value-when-inserting-data-in-sqlite/

2. If the column with the default value can not have the NOT NULL constraint (allowing NULL to be inserted), as in your question:

   you will have to omit the column with the default value from the insert query so that it gets its default.

Ideal would be:

`INSERT INTO "Table" (a, b) VALUES(1, COALESCE(NULL, DEFAULT))`

, as is in other sql dialects, which might be supported in future release:
https://sqlite.org/forum/info/d7384e085b808b05

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want nulls for column `b` then you should set it as a non null-able field as you have done with `a`

Answer (score 1):

[This solution for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2465916/1407170) should mostly work for SQLite.  The main, and albeit major, difference is that there doesn't seem to be a `Default()` function in SQLite like there is in MySQL.  I was able to replicate this functionality by keeping track of my database schema in PHP and then manually inserting the default value as the second argument to `Coalesce()`.  [See this Gist](https://gist.github.com/vote539/6050726) for example code.