# How to set a default value to a TEXT column in Sqlite?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I have a simple table. I'm trying to put a default value to a TEXT column. Here is the table query:

```
"CREATE TABLE book(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, book_id TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', book_name TEXT NOT NULL);"
```

It creates the table but the problem occurs when i try to insert a data. I was only trying with giving a book name to **book_name**, as i expected that the **book_id** would have a default value 0 to the column. But it doesn't and it adds the null value, so the row doesn't get inserted. I have also tried with this query:

```
"CREATE TABLE book(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, book_id TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\', book_name TEXT NOT NULL);"
```

But the problem remains the same. I have searched the stack overflow, and got some answers but they are old and not working for me right now. So has something changed on how to set the default value to a TEXT column in sqlite. Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT**
Here is the insert statement:

```
database.insert("book", null, cv);
```

Here **cv** is the object of **ContentValues** which contains only the value for the column **book_name**.

Comment: What was your INSERT statement?

Comment: Are you creating the table in oncreate method of SQLiteOpenHelper?

Comment: And please provide the code of how you inserted data in the table

Comment: Updated my question. 
And yes i am creating the table in onCreate. Table created without any problem. i have also checked the database using sqlite browser. Main problem is how to set the default value to the TEXT column.

Comment: You don't need to escape the apostrophes.

Comment: Cause i'm not passing any values in `cv` for `book_id`.

Comment: CREATE TABLE book
(book_id TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '')   try this

Comment: @Tashen. Tried it, doesn't work :(

Comment: In a RDBMS you could technically use a trigger to override that behavior. But in SQLite you can't.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478894/sqlite-default-value-if-null

Comment: Why do you use TEXTUAL ids?! You should use INTEGERs, instead.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can specify a default value for the column when you create the table. (It doesn't appear as though you can add a default using an **ALTER** statement, so you'll have to recreate your table.)

```
CREATE TABLE your_table_name
(MainContactName TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '')
```

---

For **Example**,

```
CREATE TABLE book(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,book TEXT DEFAULT "abc");
```

now see that , **default value is set to "abc"**

Check sqllite [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#column-constraint).

Comment: If i create the column  without `NOT NULL` then it doesn't take the empty string as default or the 'abc' as you given. it takes null. I have seen most of the previous answers but none of them are working.

Comment: you want to set column value to 'something' right by default ? right ? then this works @AbirHasan

Comment: CREATE TABLE book(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,book TEXT DEFAULT "abc");   i have tried this solution and it is working @AbirHasan

Answer (score 3):

To alter table,

```
sqlitedbInstance.execSQL("alter table myTable add column Address TEXT DEFAULT 'ABC' ");
```