# How to use literals in prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In MySQL there's the `DEFAULT` keyword which let's the DB know that it should just use the column's defined default value:

> Use the keyword DEFAULT to set a column explicitly to its default
>   value. This makes it easier to write INSERT statements that assign
>   values to all but a few columns, because it enables you to avoid
>   writing an incomplete VALUES list that does not include a value for
>   each column in the table. Otherwise, you would have to write out the
>   list of column names corresponding to each value in the VALUES list.

In theory that's nice for prepared INSERT statements. The problem is that [PHP doesn't seem to have](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php) a way to bind a `?` placeholder to the `DEFAULT` keyword, like it has for `NULL` (`PDO::PARAM_NULL`). So how can you achieve a completely general, and thus *re-usable*, prepared statement where some parameters should accept the default value some of the time (without knowing it beforehand)?

I'm currently working on a thin DB model layer and this is preventing me from making the best use of prepared statements, which is a thing if you want to use it for mass inserts.

Comment: If you want to use the default, you leave the field out of the `INSERT` statement entirely.

Comment: That wouldn't be re-usable, meaning that I would have to prepare multiple statements. One for each different set of given values.

Comment: This isn't a PHP limitation. MySQL in general doesn't allow you to write a query that says to use the default value. The default is only used when the column isn't specified.

Comment: Wrong: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: well if you still want the col in the insert query which has a default set and while inserting you dont have value for that col you may check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464535/preparing-a-mysql-insert-update-statement-with-default-values

Comment: Ahh, now I understand. Unfortunately, I still think you can't do it.

Comment: It is not a limitation of `PDO` or `PHP` for that matter: that is how prepared statements work: placeholders can only be _literals_ (`NULL` is a literal BTW). No client library can give you features that are not there in the database itself.

Comment: Right. The problem is that `DEFAULT` is a keyword, not a value.

Comment: I would revert my downvote if you post a real world example, as your question seems quite out of nowhere to me. With "real world" I mean an issue you faced with in your real project before, not a sketch you devised off your head.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: Your search-fu is obviously stronger than mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave out from the `INSERT` statement the columns you want to be filled with the default value, explicitly specifying the column names where you *do* put a non-necessarily-default value.

EDIT: if you want a "completely general, and thus re-usable, prepared statement" you can't have it. The closest thing to what you ask is the following workaround:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE theTable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES
    (COALESCE(?,DEFAULT(column1)),
    (COALESCE(?,DEFAULT(column2)),
    (COALESCE(?,DEFAULT(column3)))
```

This approach implies that you pass NULL when you want DEFAULT, but satisfies partially what you ask as the name of the columns is fixed.

Comment: Again, that wouldn't let me create one re-usable statement for different sets of given values, which is one of their main benefits.

Comment: @DanMan you actually understand it wrong. Nowhere prepared statements intended for that.

Comment: Except for here, of course: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php Just go away already.

Comment: @DanMan unfortunately, I can't. It is my duty as a good citizen to help ones who mistaken. So, you ned to read that text more carefully. Nowhere it says you can use prepared statement for *arbitrary* sets of given values

Comment: @DanMan ok, I understand. See my edit. It's not a solution but a workaround. I personally would avoid something like that. But if you like it, it's your choice.