# MySQL, DEFAULT not working when inserting with prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, insert, prepared-statement

I want run an insert command using a prepared statement in which a column should use its default value.

Here's a table.

```
CREATE TABLE food (italian VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pasta') Engine MyISAM;
```

Here are some MySQL commands.

```
PREPARE statement FROM 'INSERT INTO food VALUES(?)';
SET @italian = DEFAULT;
EXECUTE statement USING @italian;
```

I get a syntax error at the `SET @italian = DEFAULT;` line.

However, if I run the following command...

```
INSERT INTO food VALUES(DEFAULT);
```

...no syntax error. The default value of 'pasta' is inserted with no problem.

What is wrong with the prepared statement syntax?

Comment: DEFAULT is a literal whereas you're trying to use a variable.  Pass in a NULL value and the DEFULT 'pasta' defined on the table will be applied on insert.

Comment: @xQbert I set the column to NOT NULL, so if I try that, MySQL throws an error saying that 'italian cannot be NULL'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464535/preparing-a-mysql-insert-update-statement-with-default-values seems to have it resolved.

Comment: @xQbert While that question is similar, their situations/solutions use pdo's and Coalesce and all kinds of stuff that I hope not to be required to use. This just seems like something that should be simple. I want to prepare a statement, and each time I execute it, decide whether to use an explicit value or the default value. There has to be a simple way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your goal but:

```
PREPARE statement FROM 'INSERT INTO food VALUES(?)';
SET @italian = NULL;
EXECUTE statement USING @italian;
```

Comment: I set the column to `NOT NULL`, so if I try to execute the above statement, MySQL throws an error saying that 'italian cannot be NULL'.
And the reason I set it to `NOT NULL` is because if I didn't, the above statement would set italian to NULL, instead of its default value of 'pasta'. My goal is stated in the first sentence of my post.

Comment: can you try: `EXECUTE statement ;`  ?

Comment: If I use `EXECUTE statement USING @italian;` it gives the error I mentioned above: `Column 'italian' cannot be null`
If I simply type `EXECUTE statement ;` then the error is `Incorrect arguments to EXECUTE`.

Comment: :-) do you really need this case be executed?

Comment: Although I love Italian food, this example is a dummy example. I just want to know conceptually what is the 'Prepare statement' equivalent of the `INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (DEFAULT);` statement.

Comment: there is no 100% equivalent statement. The closest one `EXECUTE statement USING NULL;` must insert default value. but if you set `NOT NULL` mysql doesn't accept the NULL as argument - that is your problem. So you can try to change statement to 'INSERT INTO food VALUES()'; :-) but it has even less real sense then :-)